# Java Spring TransientPropertyValueException with @OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have the following classes:

A Product class:

```
package com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCTS")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Item.class,
            mappedBy = "product",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public Product(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
package com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.dao;

import com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Product;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ProductDao extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer> {
}
```

Now, an Item class:

```
package com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMS")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "PRICE")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "QUANTITY")
    private int quantity;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private BigDecimal value;

    @JoinColumn(name="INVOICE_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Invoice invoice;

    public Item(Product product, String price, int quantity) {
        this.product = product;
        this.product.getItems().add(this);

        this.price = new BigDecimal(price);
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.value = this.price.multiply(new BigDecimal(quantity));
    }

    public void setInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
        this.invoice = invoice;
        invoice.getItems().add(this);
    }
}
```

```
package com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.dao;

import com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Item;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ItemDao extends CrudRepository<Item, Integer> {
}
```

And an Invoice class:

```
package com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name="INVOICES")
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NUMBER")
    private String number;

    @OneToMany(
            targetEntity = Item.class,
            mappedBy = "invoice",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public Invoice(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

```
package com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.dao;

import com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Invoice;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface InvoiceDao extends CrudRepository<Invoice, Integer> {
}
```

Now, when I am running a unit test with these classes, I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Item.product -> com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Product; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Item.product -> com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Product
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Item.product -> com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Product; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Item.product -> com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Product
```

The unit test code looks like such:

```
package com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.dao;

import com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Invoice;
import com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Item;
import com.springtraining.hibernate.invoice.Product;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.Arrays;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class InvoiceDaoTestSuite {
    @Autowired
    private InvoiceDao invoiceDao;

    @Test
    public void testInvoiceDaoSave() {
        // Given
        Product product1 = new Product("prod1");
        Product product2 = new Product("prod2");

        Item item1 = new Item(product1, "100", 10);
        Item item2 = new Item(product1, "200", 10);
        Item item3 = new Item(product2, "50", 2);
        Item item4 = new Item(product2, "250", 25);

        Invoice invoice1 = new Invoice("HK-47");
        item2.setInvoice(invoice1);
        item3.setInvoice(invoice1);

        Invoice invoice2 = new Invoice("HK-48");
        item1.setInvoice(invoice2);
        item4.setInvoice(invoice2);

        // When
        invoiceDao.save(invoice1);
        invoiceDao.save(invoice2);

        int invoice1_id = invoice1.getId();
        int invoice2_id = invoice2.getId();

        // Then
        Assert.assertNotEquals(0, invoice1_id);
        Assert.assertNotEquals(0, invoice2_id);

        Assert.assertTrue(invoice1.getItems().containsAll(Arrays.asList(item2, item3)));
        Assert.assertTrue(invoice2.getItems().containsAll(Arrays.asList(item1, item4)));

        Assert.assertTrue(product1.getItems().containsAll(Arrays.asList(item1, item2)));
        Assert.assertTrue(product1.getItems().containsAll(Arrays.asList(item3, item4)));

        // Clean-up
        try {
            invoiceDao.deleteById(invoice1_id);
            invoiceDao.deleteById(invoice2_id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

I have been looking at this code for a few hours now, and I still do not get it, where I have missed something. Saving Invoice entity, should automatically instantiate Item and Product objects associated with it as well.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `public class Item`, add `@ManyToOne` **cascade = CascadeType.ALL** property, like so:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Product product;

@JoinColumn(name = "INVOICE_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Invoice invoice;
```

When you create a *new* entity, using the keyword `new`, it is in the `Transient` state. To persist/save it to the DB, you first need to add it to the `Persistence Context`. `CascadeType.ALL` includes `CascadeType.PERSIST`, which will instruct `Hibernate` to **persist** the *product* and *invoice* entities.

Also, remove the `@NotNull` on your entity fields annotated by `@Id`. It is not required, since your field is a primary key and instead of this

<s>invoiceDao.save(invoice1);</s>
<s>invoiceDao.save(invoice2);</s>
<s>int invoice1_id = invoice1.getId();</s>
<s>int invoice2_id = invoice2.getId();</s>

You can do:

```
int invoice1_id = invoiceDao.save(invoice1).getId();
int invoice2_id = invoiceDao.save(invoice2).getId();
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so much, I have been stuck on this problem since yesterday evening. So, the rule of the thumb to remember here, is that if I have a 1:N relationship, both sides of that relationship have to be marked with CascadeType.PERSIST at a very minimum?

Comment: Almost there. The rule of thumb is to do a `CascadeType.PERSIST` on the "associated" entities that you want to `persist`. (Knowing the 4 states of an entity's life cycle also helps).